# Three image rectification

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

Have anyone tried or know if it is possible to rectify three images in opencv?
I have three cameras in a "L" setup. Meaning one camera in "the middle", one under it, and one next to it. I can rectify them easily by pairs, just doing vertical and horizontal rectification, but i cannot figure out if it is possible to rectify them all to the same image plane with opencv.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do it in general case.

To do this, camera centers must lie on a line. So, in this case it is possible to get a bunch of planes which contain the line. If you take such plane and intersect with the image plane of any camera, you will get epipolar line corresponding to the chosen plane.

But if the camera centers are not coplanar, then there exists only one plane. So you will get only one epipolar line for each camera, but to rectify the images you will need a set of lines that covers entire image.